# Hide rows in Excel based off multiple column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

How can I hide rows based off multiple column values? Example: If the "Projects", "Team Member", "Priority", & "Status" fields are all blank, then the row will hide itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your other post, and I don't really think this is the way you should go about building your dashboard. You are essentially creating a copy of your other sheet. It seems like an `Advance Filter` would be better suited here.

If you are set on your current method, this will determine lowest used cell in your columns, and hide rows above that cell based on your criteria. I would add a command button named something like **"Refresh My Dash"** and link it to this macro.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideRow()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LRowC, LRowD, LRowF, LRowH, LRow As Long
    LRowC = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowD = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowF = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRowH = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LRowC, LRowD, LRowF, LRowH)

Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.Rows.Hidden = False
    For i = LRow To 2 Step -1
        If ws.Range("C" & i).Text = "" And ws.Range("D" & i).Text = "" And ws.Range("F" & i).Text = "" And ws.Range("H" & i).Text = "" Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```